# Get previous month value based on month value in a cell in excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

How do I get previous month in abbreviated form based on text value in another cell

```
Suppose: 
A1 = Nov

I need: 
B1 = Oct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B1 =TEXT(EDATE(--(A1&1),-1),"mmm")